# G1ANT Studio Advance Course Lesson 8 Error

Tags: g1ant

Error Image occuring in advance course Lesson 8:

[image: Error Image occuring in advance course Lesson 8]

Code used is

```
program mtsc
♥rdc = /ui[@name='Remote Desktop Connection']
waitfor.ui ‴♥rdc/ui[@id='5017']/ui[@name='Show Options ']‴
ui.click ‴♥rdc/ui[@id='5017']/ui[@name='Show Options ']‴
ui.settext ‴♥rdc/ui[@typeid='50003']/ui[@typeid='50004']‴ text test.domain.com
delay 1
ui.settext ‴♥rdc/ui[@id='13064']‴ text admin
```

When I am executing program their is error occuring at 4th line of code i.e. "

```
Exception of type FlaUI.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotAvailableException'
```

was thrown" kindly give solution on this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the wpath address of the combox and paste it in the code instead of "rdc/ui[@typeid='50003']/ui[@typeid='50004".
And don't use rdc in front of that wpath, it will run the code.
You can refer my assignment video. I have shown in that how can we remove this error.